# Using the component's function outside of the component in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
const DayScaleCell = props => (
    <WeekView.DayScaleCell
      {...props}
      onClick={() => Calendar.changeCurrDate(props.startDate)}
    />
  );

class Calendar extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            userId: fire.auth().currentUser.uid,
            data: appointments,
            currentDate: new Date(), // set to today's date by default
            message: '',
            open: false,
            selectedDate: new Date(),
        };
    }


    changeCurrDate = (date) => {
        this.setState({
            currentDate: date.getDate(),
        })
    }

    ....
```

The const `DayScaleCell` overrides an element in an external component that I am using in the `Calendar` component. I am trying to change a state when I click that element when it is clicked.

https://codesandbox.io/s/llqmkq887

This is the demo that I followed, and the demo `console.log`s the date clicked. I was trying the get the date of the clicked date (e.g. 19) and assign it to the `currentDate` state in my component.

However, my way gives me an error `TypeError: Calendar.changeCurrDate is not a function`. What would be a way to do this?

Comment: Create a service with that function and import the service where ever you want. That way you can use the function anywhere.

Comment: @OrthoHomeDefense sorry, i don't get what you mean.

Comment: `changeCurrDate` is a method on an **instance** of `Calendar`, not if the class itself.

Comment: @FelixKling how could I fix it?

Comment: Not sure, I'm not familiar with that library.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is to write `DayScaleCell` in some sort of high order function. That will accept additional data, and then returns component itself

```
const getDayScaleCellComponent = onCellClick => props => (
  <WeekView.DayScaleCell
    {...props}
    onClick={() => onCellClick(props.startDate)}
  />
);
```

Using it in `Calendar` component

```
<WeekView
  startDayHour={9}
  endDayHour={19}
  dayScaleCellComponent={getDayScaleCellComponent(this.changeCurrDate)}
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how to pass a function to that component. https://codesandbox.io/s/189zv041n4

The WeekView Component needed a change to allow for a function to be passed in

```
 const DayScaleCell = (props, func) => (
     <WeekView.DayScaleCell {...props} onClick={() => func()} />
);
```

After that it is a simple matter of passing in the props and the function

```
<WeekView
     startDayHour={9}
     endDayHour={19}
     dayScaleCellComponent={(e) => DayScaleCell(e, this.onChange)}
            />
```

The function that is being passed in increments the count state for the app class.

Comment: Thank you so much! Best answer.